# FLINT/C installation on Arch

Tags: bash, makefile, automake, binutils

I'm trying to install FLINT/C lib on Arch for learning Modern Cryptography in C. All my dependencies are fulfilled per se and the only thing left to do is run `make && make install` and ld is generating errors :

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/venine/Downloads/flint-2.4.5'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/venine/Downloads/flint-2.4.5/ulong_extras'
CC   ../build/ulong_extras/../ulong_extras.lo
/usr/bin/ld: -r and -pie may not be used together
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status     
make[2]: *** [../Makefile.subdirs:55: 
../build/ulong_extras/../ulong_extras.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/venine/Downloads/flint- 2.4.5/ulong_extras'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:135: libflint.so] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/venine/Downloads/flint-2.4.5'
make: *** [Makefile:161: library] Error 2`
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong and how do I create a proper make file

Comment: The make script used tries to execute `ld` command with both `-r` and `pie` and it does no like it.BTW, without the make script is hard to help more, check the [mcve] page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be [FLINT 2 Issue#400](https://github.com/wbhart/flint2/issues/400). The bug also describes a change in the makefile.

Comment: Any idea as to how to apply this patch. It's slowly becoming a headache

Comment: Assuming your Makefile and downloaded patch are in the same directory, you could just say `patch -p1 < makefile.patch`

Comment: Never mind, I manually edited the Makefile.subdirs
It was only a matter of few parameters. Since I was not acquainted with '$(diff)', I got sort of got confused with the syntax regarding '-' and '+' in the patch. I got it working now !